# QX11EmbedContainer and QProcess problem

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qprocess, qx11embedcontainer

I've been trying to put a QX11EmbedContainer in my app, and I need to start a terminal within it (because with konsolepart I can practically do nothing).

```
QX11EmbedContainer* container = new QX11EmbedContainer(this); // with or without "this" I got the same result
container->show(); 
QProcess process(container);
QString executable("xterm -into ");
QStringList arguments;
arguments << QString::number(container->winId());
process.start(executable, arguments);
```

compilation goes fine,but I got this message:

```
QProcess: Destroyed while process is still running.
```

and I'm not able to see the container, suggestions?????? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `QProcess` is allocated on the stack and will deleted as soon as it goes out of scope. This is likely to happen before the the "xterm" child process quits (hence the output).

Try allocating the QProcess in the heap instead:

```
QProcess * process = new QProcess(container);
...
process->start(executable, arguments);
```

You can delete the QProcess in three ways:

1. Do nothing. Let the `QX11EmbedContainer` delete it. It is a child of the `QX11EmbedContainer` and will be deleted when the `QX11EmbedContainer` is deleted.
2. Hook up the `finished()` signal to its own `deleteLater()` slot.

   `connect( process, SIGNAL(finished(int,QProcess::ExitStatus)), process, SLOT(deleteLater()) );`
3. Delete it yourself by retaining a pointer to it and delete that pointer later.

As an extra note, I'm suspicious of the first parameter to `QProcess::start()`. It should be the path to your executable and further arguments should be added to the `QStringlist`.

```
QProcess * process = new QProcess(container);
QString executable("xterm"); // perhaps try "/usr/X11/bin/xterm"
QStringList arguments;
arguments << "-into";
arguments << QString::number(container->winId());
proces->start(executable, arguments);
```